# jquery UI autocomplete drop-down list not showing up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery UI autocomplete and for some reason I can't figure out why the drop-down list is not showing up.  I've tried everything I can think of with no luck... I am hope some can help me. Firebug shows the correct JSON output from my PHP script.

The alert(data) under success shows:  [object Object]

**HTML code**

```
<select name=key1 id=key1>
  <option selected value="">CHOOSE ONE </option>
  <option value="allrecs">ALL RECORDS <</option>
  <option value="citnumb">CIT NUMBER <<option>
  <option value="sernumb">SERIAL NUMBER </option>
  <option value="model">MODEL </option>
</select>

<input type="text" size=30 name="qvalue" id="qvalue">
```

**JQUERY script**

```
$("#qvalue").autocomplete(  
{
  source: function(request, response) 
  {
    $.ajax(
    {
      url: "jqsuggest2.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data:{term: request.term,searchkey:$('#key1').val()
    },
    success: function(data) 
    {
      alert(data);
      response( $.map( data, function(item) 
      {
         return 
         {
            value: item.term
         }
       }));
                }
        });
  },
  minLength: 2

});
```

**PHP script**

```
        $json = '[';
        $first = true;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            if (!$first)
            { 
                $json .=  ','; 
            }
            else
            {
                $first = false; 
            }

            if ($searchkey == "citnumb")
            {
                $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['citnum'].'"}';
            }
            if ($searchkey == "sernumb")
            {
                $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['sernum'].'"}';
            }
            elseif ($searchkey == "model")
            {
                $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['model'].'"}';
            }

        }
        $json .= ']';
        echo $json;
        }
```

**Firebug output**
[{"value":"28225"}]

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the an array to the `source` option. I believe if you change the return statement in your map function, you should be set to go. So, change

```
return 
{
    value: item.term
}
```

to

```
return item.source
```

Comment: Willam:  I got the following error... "missing ; before statement
http://tobagoborn.com/javascript/jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js
Line 16".... Which prompted to use goggle's jquery CDN....  I added back the {}'s and changed item.term to item.value and now it works!!

Thanks for the assist!!!

Comment: oh yeah...should be `item.source`...  Glad you figured it out at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`$.map` is used to transform one array into another array. In the context of the autocomplete widget, it is used to transform a source array into an array in the format that the autocomplete widget expects.

In your case, it *looks* like your php is returning an array with objects structured like this:

```
[{ "value": "1234"}, ... ]
```

Turns out this is a valid array for autocomplete to use. You shouldn't need any post processing. In other words, this should work for you:

```
$("#qvalue").autocomplete(  
{
  source: "jqsuggest2.php",
  minLength: 2
});
```

In fact, you could shorten your PHP to just return an array of strings:

```
["1234", "4567", "89101"]
```

Which is also a valid array for autocomplete to use.

Comment: I'm curious about the format of strings sent from a server to the Autocomplete widget. The jQuery Autocomplete documentation says, "When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP)." So I have used JSON. You clearly know this code. Is JSON not necessary for a remote server feeding Autocomplete? Is that a change and the documentation is incorrect? What's the deal?

Comment: Yes, a remote server must return JSON-formatted data for the plugin to consume. Supplying a string simply lets the widget know to use AJAX to retrieve the JSON data via the supplied URL.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I don't understand this supplying a string to get an ajax retrieve of JSON.  But your comment confirms I should be generating JSON in the php and using data: JSON; in Autocomplete to get it. Thanks.